# Blockchain decentralised database on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blockchain

I want to store the data of my rails application on a blockchain technology where data is decentralised. any quick tutorials or reference articles from where I can learn how to do so?

I want to store JSON data inside blockchain and I want to use any external service.

And any reliable blockchain as a service people like heroku for rails to get started?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this thread n [ethereum and rails](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2812/87) integration.

Comment: You'll need to give more information than that or risk getting closed for "too broad". Do you intend to start your own blockchain service? Do you intend to use somebody else's blockchain to store some data in? (such as http://www.righto.com/2014/02/ascii-bernanke-wikileaks-photographs.html) And mannnnny more feasibility issues inside....

Comment: @bbozo Updated. Kindly answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to handle this with Database setup.
Go through this document https://www.bigchaindb.com/whitepaper/bigchaindb-whitepaper.pdf. 
Also, see how this is done with python. Think this would be helpful https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-data-storage-with-blockchain-and-bigchaindb/